# Access mongo instance in Flask Unit Tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I have a simple create_app function in `app/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from .user_management import User

from config import app_config

login_manager = LoginManager()

mongo = PyMongo()

....

def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True, static_folder='static')
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    login_manager.login_message = 'You must be logged in to view this page'
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'

    Bootstrap(app)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config])
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

    if app.testing:
        mongo.init_app(app, config_prefix='MONGO2')
    else:
        mongo.init_app(app)

   ....

    return app
```

And my config:

```
class Config():
    DEBUG = False
    MONGO_HOST = 'localhost'
    MONGO_PORT = 27017
    ....


class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    DEVELOPMENT = True


class TestingConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
    DEBUG = False
    CSRF_ENABLED = False
    MONGO2_DBNAME = 'test'
....

app_config = {
    'testing': TestingConfig,
    'development': DevelopmentConfig,
    'production': ProductionConfig
}
```

Throughout the app, I import the mongo instance from this file make use of it throughout the app. However, I can not find a find to set up a new mongo instance that uses the 'test' database without using the app context, as I'm doing here

My unit test file looks like this.

```
from app import create_app
import unittest

from app import mongo

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        app = create_app('testing')
        self.app = app

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_mongo(self):
        with self.app.app_context():
            assert mongo.db.name == 'test'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This does not seem like the way to go at all. It also makes it impossible to use the app.test_client(). What is the proper way to instantiate the test database in a flask test setting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do that via config files, but I have another approach that might interest you.

When I have been creating unit tests to my flask / mongo app, I have just simply read sys.args (in my '**__init__.py**') and decided from there if I want to use test DB or the actual DB, like this:

```
if "__init__.py" == sys.argv[0]:
    db = LoginManager()
else:
    db = TestDB()  # if running unit tests
```

I don't know is this the most robust way to work with unit tests, but it is most certainly is super simple way to do it, and does the job.

If you are interested about the whole setup, check out my [example app](https://github.com/mojotti/restful_api_with_mongo_db).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to re-create the mongo object in each different unit test that needs to access a different database defined in your config. Here is how I did it and to get a real test I wrote a value to the database and made sure I could read it back two different ways:

```
import uuid
from datetime import datetime
from flask_testing import TestCase
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from project import app

class TestMongoDev(TestCase):
    def create_app(self):
        app.config.from_object('project.config.DevelopmentConfig')
        return app

    def test_mongo_development(self):
        mongo = PyMongo(app)
        testval = str(uuid.uuid4())
        inserted_id = mongo.db.test.insert_one({
            'testedAt': datetime.now(),
            'testval': testval
        }).inserted_id
        self.assertTrue(mongo.db.name == 'dev')
        self.assertTrue(mongo.db.test.find_one({'testval': testval})['testval'] == testval)
        self.assertTrue(mongo.db.test.find_one({'_id': inserted_id})['testval'] == testval)


class TestMongoTest(TestCase):
    def create_app(self):
        app.config.from_object('project.config.TestingConfig')
        return app

    def test_mongo_testing(self):
        mongo = PyMongo(app)
        testval = str(uuid.uuid4())
        inserted_id = mongo.db.test.insert_one({
            'testedAt': datetime.now(),
            'testval': testval
        }).inserted_id
        self.assertTrue(mongo.db.name == 'test')
        self.assertTrue(mongo.db.test.find_one({'testval': testval})['testval'] == testval)
        self.assertTrue(mongo.db.test.find_one({'_id': inserted_id})['testval'] == testval)


class TestMongoProd(TestCase):
    def create_app(self):
        app.config.from_object('project.config.ProductionConfig')
        return app

    def test_mongo_production(self):
        mongo = PyMongo(app)
        testval = str(uuid.uuid4())
        inserted_id = mongo.db.test.insert_one({
            'testedAt': datetime.now(),
            'testval': testval
        }).inserted_id
        self.assertTrue(mongo.db.name == 'prod')
        self.assertTrue(mongo.db.test.find_one({'testval': testval})['testval'] == testval)
        self.assertTrue(mongo.db.test.find_one({'_id': inserted_id})['testval'] == testval)
```